# Dropdown holding of value in Angular view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a unique situation. I have a dropdown called caseStatus (see code below) and it is actually being written out during an ng-repeat, but it is tied to a model that contains the list of Case Statuses.  Obviously there are multiple of these dropdowns on the page once it is rendered. All of that works just fine. The issue is that the judge can change the status of the case. I am working on a function that will handle that and I am confident it will work. My question is how to do the following two things (which are perhaps both solved with one method I suspect):

1. Make sure that each dropdown maintains its last value when a page is refreshed or returned to.
2. Make sure that it loads to what was last there during the ng-repeat. There is a field in the model that the ng-repeat is using that has the value for the Case Status.

Here is the code. There is a comment that says which dropdown is in question:

```
<div ng-controller="CaseListCtrl">
    <div class="row" ng-show="$parent.loggedin">
        <div class="col-sm-12 calselectrow">
            <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar calicon"></span>

                <input type="text" id="calpick" ng-model="date" jdatepicker />
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar calclick"></i>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary flat-edge">>></a>

                <span class="bluedept">Department:</span>
                <select class="selectpicker deptpicker" id="deptSelect" selectpicker data-ng-model="department" ng-change="getCalendar();">
                    <option ng-repeat="department in departments">{{department.CourtRoom}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-show="$parent.loggedin">
        <div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 caselist" ng-model="cases" ng-repeat-start="case in cases |  orderBy: ['sequence', 'AmPm', 'Sched_Time', 'Case_Number']">
                <div class="sequence">
                    <input type=text class="seq-box" size="1" value="{{case.sequence}}" />
                    <!-- Add hidden field to hold the CalendarID value for updating the sequence later-->
                    <input type="hidden" name="CalendarID_{{case.Case_Number}}" value="{{case.CalendarID}}" />
                </div>
                <div class="casetitle">
                    <span class="caselink">{{case.Case_Number}}</span>
                    <a href="calendar" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Calendar" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view" tooltip>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="documents/{{case.Case_Number}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Documents" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view" tooltip>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="parties/{{case.Case_Number}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Parties" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view" tooltip>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                    </a>
                    <select class="form-control" id="caseStatus" name="caseStatus" ng-model="caseStatus.statusID" ng-change="setStatus();" ng-options="castStatus.statusName for caseStatus in castStatus track by caseStatus.statusName" required></select><!-- This is the dropdown in question-->
                        {{case.Case_Title}}
</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 caselist-bottom">
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="hearing-time">{{case.Sched_Time}}&nbsp;{{case.AmPm}}</div>
                    <div class="hearing-title">{{case.Event}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat-end></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing a SPA (single page application)?  What do you mean by "page is refreshed or returned to"?  If you are reloading the whole page, then there is no way to retrieve the last values, as the controllers will reinitialize.  You'll have to save the values somewhere, e.g. database or cookie, and retrieve them from a service that is injected into your controller...

Comment: Yes, it is SPA, but that doesn't stop the user from hitting the refresh button, right? :-) I have some mechanisms in place to handle that for other things. In fact, I am wondering if I am crossing the bridge too soon. Perhaps when i actually have live data to test with this won't be an issue? Afterall, the data will be saved to a database and upon hitting the refresh button everything reloads, including the model with the data, so the real question is how to set that dropdown to have the value in the database as its selected value upon display?

Comment: Ok, so let's say the case status is saved to the database on change of the select.  If the user hits the refresh button, then you'll controller will get initialized.  The controller should get this saved data from a service, which is injected to the controller, and then when that service call finishes, e.g. promise is resolved, then you populate the model tied to the select with the value, which in this case is caseStatus.statusID.

Comment: OK, but what about the fact that there are going to be many of these all with potentially different values?

Comment: Instead of ng-model="caseStatus.statusId", it should bind to "case" in the ng-repeat, e.g. ng-model="case.statusId", assuming each case has the statusId associated with it.  This is the value that should be saved to the database.